# Code or Server issue - PHP contact form?

Tags: php

I'm redesigning a site, and having just uploaded the files to the host, am now testing that everything works. The message form is not working consistently - sometimes it sends the user to the thank you confirmation page and sometimes it displays the error: "500 Internal Server Error, The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request." However, no test email has arrived at the recipient address showing that the form has worked. Strangely, it successfully went through when I substituted my personal email address in the mailer.php document. This makes me think that the code works.

I'm suspecting that this is a server or email configuration issue, because I've also been having issues with email, after changing hosts, but possibly it has to do with my code?

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="mailer.php" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2"><small>Name</small></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Enter your full name" required>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2"><small>Email</small></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter your email, example@domain.com" required>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2"><small>Telephone</small></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" name="inputPhone" placeholder="Enter your telephone number" required>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="message" class="col-sm-2"><small>Message</small></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="inputMessage" id="inputMessage" placeholder="Enter your message here" required></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<!-- The following field is for robots only, invisible to humans: -->
    <p class="robotic" id="pot">
        <label>If you're human leave this blank:</label>
            <input name="robotest" type="text" name="robotest" id="robotest" class="robotest" />
    </p>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        <input style="font-size:22px;" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
    <! Will be used to display an alert to the user>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

mailer.php file:

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail = "info@domain.com";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$name = check_input($_POST['inputName'], "Your name was not entered correctly.");
$email = check_input($_POST['inputEmail'], "Your email address was not entered correctly.");
$phone = check_input($_POST['inputPhone'], "Your telephone number was not entered correctly.");
$message = check_input($_POST['inputMessage'], "Your message was not entered correctly.");
$robotest = $_POST['robotest'];

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("Invalid e-mail address.");
}

/* ROBOT TEST */
if($robotest)
{
show_error("Denied, robot.");
}

/*  prepare the message for the e-mail */

$subject = "Inquiry from Website";

$message = "

Someone has sent you a message using your website's contact form:

Name: $name
Email: $email
Telephone: $phone
Subject: $subject

Message:
$message

";

/* send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: http://www.website.com/thankyou.html');
exit();

/* functions used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>

<p>Please correct the following error:</p>
<strong><?php echo $myError; ?></strong>
<p>Hit the back button and try again.</p>

</body>
</html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Some webhosting companies have a stupid policy. You need to address a `setFrom` address. And this address must exists in your server. I mean, if you add `no-reply@yourdomain.com` in the `setFrom`, then `no-reply@yourdomain.com` should exist as an email setup on your domain.

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but I've had numerous issues using the mail() command - I resorted to using [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) - in my case it solved issues where I couldn't get the standard PHP `mail()` to work with SSL/TLS but it may also help you with your issue.

Comment: check your SMTP server logs. They usually are in /var/log/mail for GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have a server/configuration problem. I've used this code and put it on my own server and it works perfectly fine. (also, nice work, very clean code)

One thing to think about when checking whether you get emails or not (specifically when a personal email works, but a corporate one does not) is email heuristics. Try changing the content setup and/or the subject line. (the subject line looks suspcious to me, I'd start there).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_spam_filtering